# freedb.org - How to query by artist/album without disc id

Tags: c#, web-services, screen-scraping, web-scraping

I am working on a C# program that will (hopefully) standardize the genres in my mp3 files. To do it I am going to try and use last.fm, discogs, freedb, and any other online music database I can find to return genres for each album. I plan on taking the results between these databases to automatically calculate a genre/genre list for my mp3s.

It appears that freedb was intended to return data based on a disc id from a ripped CD. What I would like to do is query freedb in a similar way last.fm lets you query, by artist/album and then return results from matching entries.

My question is what is the best way to do this? It doesn't look like freedb allows REST calls. Would I need to do some web scraping to achieve this? Are there any open source applications scraping freedb data that I can look at?

Thanks!
Jason

Answer (score 2):

The freedb database is free to download and use however you would like.  You could always download it, import it into a local db, and then query it however you'd like.

[The database](http://www.freedb.org/en/download__database.10.html)

[Parser for the freedb database](https://github.com/ayende/XmcdParser)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am looking for a way to do this over the web so I don't have to maintain a local copy of the database.

Answer (score -1):

Lastfm and some other music service have an open data table, I would try querying them with [yql](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/)